# cannot delete builds in tfs 2012

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2012

I am trying to delete some build definitions for a specific range of time by using tfsbuild delete command. After waiting for about 3 hours I get the error message:

> Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: InformationField, Fields, BuildInformationNode, Information, BuildDetails, Builds, BuilQueryResult, QueryBuildsResult, QueryBuildsResponse, Body, Envelope. Line1, position 1240.

Does anybody know what could be the problem? Other builds are deleted successfully in the same collection.

Comment: People experiencing this previously seem to find that it was a firewall/proxy issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/741401/error-loading-builds-in-tfs-vs2010

Comment: As other builds on the same server and same collection can be deleted, I think all is fine with firewall/proxy. Thanks for link

Comment: It may be that the individual log contains something that causes the issue. The error comes from a SOAP protocol error where the SOAP call to TFS isn't passed completely to the client. This is almost always caused by something that sits between the TFS process and the Client. A proxy, firewall, anti-virus solution, slow VPN can be the cause of it. It can be very specific to this one build. Can you open the build directly from the TFS server itself or in Web Access?

Comment: I started deleting build by a very small range (10 days interval, for example: 2014-12-01 till 2014-12-10). We have a long history for these builds, it will take quote a lot time, but at least it works. So probably the problem was that sending request to tfs server was too large. Thanks for taking a look to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started deleting build by a very small range (10 days interval, for example: 2014-12-01 till 2014-12-10). We have a long history for these builds, it will take quote a lot time, but at least it works. So probably the problem was that sending request to tfs server was too large.